# Adding items to an object array from another array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I am currently learning python and working on my first project. I am stuck at a problem. I have a dictionary like this:

```
tickets_details ={"ticket": ["ticket1", "ticket2", "ticket3"]}
```

and I have another array of objects like this:

```
obj = [
       {"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M"},
       {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F"},
       {"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F"},
      ]
```

What I want to do is combine both so that my desired output looks like this:

```
result = [
       {"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M", "ticket":"ticket1"},
       {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F", "ticket":"ticket2"},
       {"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F", "ticket":"ticket3"},
      ]
```

I know how it's done in javascript but not so familiar with python. Please help me solve my problem. Sorry if it's trivial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```py
obj = [
       {"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M"},
       {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F"},
       {"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F"},
      ]

tickets_details ={"ticket": ["ticket1", "ticket2", "ticket3"]}

for i in range(len(obj)):
    obj[i]["ticket"] = tickets_details["ticket"][i]

print(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, using zip:

```
def update(x,y):
  z = x
  z["tickets"] = y
  return z

result = [update(a,b) for (a,b) in zip(obj, tickets_details["ticket"])]
```

This will take the corresponding ticket for each item in the first list, and add it as a new key to the object.

If you want to update `obj` in place, you could instead do this:

```
def update(x,y):
  x["tickets"] = y

[update(a,b) for (a,b) in zip(obj, tickets_details["ticket"])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of elements in `ticket_details["ticket"]` and `obj` is the same,
all you need is a for-loop with the iterator being the index into the arrays.
Some things that may help are the `range()` and the `len()` functions.

[`range(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) returns a sequence of numbers from 0 to n - 1:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i) # will print out 0, 1, 2
```

[`len(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) returns the length of an array or an object:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(len(x)) # will print out 4
```

Lastly, to add something to an existing object, you need to provide the **key** in the key-value pair before assigning a value:

```
object = {"a":"hello", "b":"world"}
object["c"] = "bananas!"
print(object) # will print {'a': 'hello', 'b': 'world', 'c': 'bananas!'}
```